# Add a CompassOverlay and get errors

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I want to add a compassoverlay, but I get some errors:

```
this.mCompassOverlay = new CompassOverlay(context, new InternalCompassOrientationProvider(context), mMapView);
mMapView.getOverlays().add(this.mCompassOverlay);
```

Can not resolve Symbol 'mCompassOverlay'
and
Can not resolve Symbol 'context'

Where I get the "Symbols"?

Comment: you have to give more context ( more code )

Comment: Please add the osmdroid tag if your question is about the osmdroid library.

Answer (score 1):

resolved:

```
CompassOverlay mCompassOverlay = new CompassOverlay(this, new InternalCompassOrientationProvider(this), map);
mCompassOverlay.enableCompass();
map.getOverlays().add(mCompassOverlay);
```